# Downvote Flood in my Account?

Tags: discussion

Several of my posts has gotten downvoted in the **past 7 hours**.

A partial concern is my rep, but that's very minor, my main reason here is if the *system* downvoted me or something.

About **9 questions/answers** so far today.

I would say it's around **15 questions/answers** (*today and yesterday*) victim to this, and in the past 7 days, there may have been more (my good question record isn't THE best, so it's sorta hard to tell.)

Is there any particular reason for this? Or is there just some downvote spammer. Is this even against the rules?

Comment: The mods and community team will investigate and take action if appropriate.

Comment: I'll look into this later today. It's entirely possible [the system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) will _revert_ votes automatically. But it won't add downvotes as a rule. (There is an edge case around spam flags, but that's not the situation here.) If there is some action to be taken, I probably _won't_ report back here due to the [Streisand Effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23385/1438).

Comment: I'm not sure how to say this politely ... couldn't it just be that you ask [lots of crap questions](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2383/warspyking?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=5)? :-p If there is a 'downvote spammer', their DVs should be reversed automatically - right @moderators? So if you suddenly get a whole bunch of DVs removed, you know you've become part of one of those DV vendettas (I suspect there is or has been a lot of that on Puzzling); if not, just try to write better questions! :-)

Comment: @rand al'thor I take no offence to that, in fact, I thank you for being honest. I understand that, but it seemed to me as if I had a bunch of downvotes slammed down on me in a few hours. I think I MAY have gotten them back, not entirely sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...my main reason here is if the *system* downvoted me or something.

This shouldn't be a concern. The system doesn't downvote you. I think there *used* to be an automatic downvote applied for some close reasons, but I don't think that is the case any more. Either way, it wouldn't go on a spree like that.

Most likely it's just your garden-variety [Serial Downvoter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/212780). There's a script that should detect this, but it takes some time. The usual advice is to wait 24-48 hours to let the script run its course. After that:

> If the 24 hours has already passed and the suspicious votes have not been reversed, you can then flag one of your posts and explain what happened so a moderator can look into it. It is generally preferred that you avoid asking about them on a site's Meta since details of the investigation cannot be divulged and you won't actually get any information that will be useful to other members of the community.

Of course, it's *possible* that this is a big coincidence, and those votes didn't all come from one person/user. If that's the case, I guess the mods will let you know about it after you flag it for their attention.

This happened to me a week or so ago (only 8 posts, I think, but all within 3 minutes). It was detected and reversed the following day.